# Batch file opens Default Browser instead of Firefox

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have a login script that runs for every user. The first check sees if the username matches our Test-Taking User (exam). If so, launches Firefox to the exam homepage and stops.

The commands individually work. When I call the `.bat` file, it launches Internet Explorer to the website. What am I doing wrong?

```
@echo off

REM Exam Startup - Username is "exam", then start the Exam website, and exit the script
if %USERNAME% EQU exam (
    if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"       start "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://www.example.com/"
    if exist "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"  start "%PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://www.example.com/"
    exit
)
...
REM rest of script
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

#### What am I doing wrong?

```
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" start "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://www.example.com/"
```

You have no `"title"` in your `start` command.

- If there is no `"title"` then `start` parses `"%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"` as a title (because it starts with a `"`) and `"https://www.example.com/"` as the command to execute.
- Executing the command `"https://www.example.com/"` causes the default browser to open that URL.

Try adding `""` after `start`:

```
if exist "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" start "" "%PROGRAMFILES%\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" "https://www.example.com/"
```

---

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters] Key:
> ```
>
> - `title`       Text for the CMD window title bar (required.)
> - `path`        Starting directory.
> - `command`     The command, batch file or executable program to run.
> - `parameters`  The parameters passed to the command.

...

> Always include a `title` this can be a simple string like `"My Script"` or just a pair of empty quotes `""`
>
> According to the Microsoft documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.

Source [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [start](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) - Start a program, command or batch script (opens in a new window).

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, `start` interprets `...firefox.exe` as the title and the URL as what should be started and is intelligent enough to detect an URL and feed it to the default browser?

Comment: @Boldewyn: `start` indeed knows what to do with URLs, and that's to open them in the default browser.